# RGtk2 - missing gladexmlnew

Tags: r, gtk, glade

I just installed the `RGtk2` package on a new machine and `gladexmlnew` seems to be missing (i.e. I get a `could not find function gladexmlnew` error after loading the `RGtk2` package).

I have `libglade`, `libglade2` and corresponding `-devel` packages installed.

What am I missing? The help file doesn't seem to help.

---

**SOLUTION**: I seem to have found the solution, so I am posting it here. Apparently `libglade` has been deprecated in favour of GTKBuilder and `RGtk2` does not include it anymore.

[This page](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkBuilder.html) has some informations on how to migrate from `libglade` to `GTKBuilder`.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: Sorry, forgot to specify. Linux, particularly Fedora. R version 2.12.0, RGtk2 version 2.20.3

Comment: The link to "this page" does not work anymore. Do you have a code snippet how to load a glade file now using RGtk2 and GTKBuilder? THX!

Comment: @RYoda maybe this? https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkBuilder.html

Comment: @nico: THX!!! I have now found demo source code that demonstrates how to use GTKBuilder: Load the `library RGtk2` and execute the command `demo(builder)`. It explains how to use the "new" **addFromFile** method of the class **gtkBuilder**

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the follow-up. I have only two comments:

1. Version 2.20.3 loads fine on my Ubuntu machines under R 2.12.0.
2. A quick `grep -i gladexmlnew` in both the `R/` and `src/` directories of the [RGtk2](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RGtk2) package showed no hits, so this does not seem to be a symbol used by the package.

so it looks like this may be particular to your Fedora versions of the Gtk libraries.  But that is just a guess on my part.

Comment: hmmm... I'm referring to this http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/RGtk2/html/gladeXMLNew.html (sorry I forgot the capitalisation when writing the question, maybe that's why grep did not give any hits)

Comment: I used `grep -i` which ignores case. And even expanding the search to all subdirectories via 'grep -rin gladeXMLNew .', it get no hits. Also note that the html is likely to be old as R no longer produces static html pages.

Comment: Found the solution - editing my question. Thanks for your help Dirk.