# R: gWidgetsRGtk2: gladeXMLNew() function not found

Tags: r, gtk, glade

I'm trying to run the first two lines of the gWidgetsRGtk2 examples but I cannot find glade libraries in CRAN . So gladeXMLNew() function fails. Is there anybody who could help ?

```
##  This  requires  glade  libraries  to  be  installed  before  compiling  RGtk2
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

gladeFile  <-  system.file("examples/t.test.glade",package="gWidgetsRGtk2")
GUI  <-  gladeXMLNew("t.test.glade")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this question is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259282/rgtk2-missing-gladexmlnew)

Comment: You are right. I din't see it. TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "[Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is a RAD tool to enable quick & easy development of user
>   interfaces for the GTK+ toolkit and the GNOME desktop environment"

so it is both too general and too specific for CRAN