# R with RGtk2: "Hello world" example using a GUI builder (glade, GTKBuilder)?

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, glade, gtk2

I want to **create a GUI in R using RGtk2 and the [Glade GUI builder](https://glade.gnome.org/) as user interface designer**.

How can I use the XML file created by Glade in my R code (using e. g. RGtk2)?

Has anybody a "hello world" example with a simple window or a link to a a good tutorial

THX!

PS: There is a code example in the documentation of RGtk2 but it does not work since the function "gladeXMLNew" is no longer available (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259282/rgtk2-missing-gladexmlnew)).

```
> GUI <- gladeXMLNew("applicationwindow1")
Error: could not find function "gladeXMLNew"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [@nico pointed me to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259282/rgtk2-missing-gladexmlnew?noredirect=1#comment56251518_4259282):

```
library(RGtk2)
demo(builder)
# the variable "filename" points to a Glade XML file
# (which seems to be for Gtk2, not Gtk3 though)
```

**Still an open question: Is there a good tutorial for Glade with RGtk2?**